# How can I execute the lua file in init script?

Tags: lua, init, openwrt, luci

I have a problem in init script.

```
reload_service() {
    echo "####################### restart##################" > /dev/ttyS0
    lua /root/proto.lua
    lua /root/ft.lua
    /etc/init.d/network reload
}
```

From that code, everything is fine, but I can't see the result of the two lua files(In those files, I put the print function. When i typed the lua command in command line, I can see the print function's result).
In init script, can i use the lua command?

Comment: In init script, how can i execute the lua file? is my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, It works. It isn't seen the print result, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: given the low quality of your question I suggest you delete it. or you read [ask], improve your post and then answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use syslog for logging, print statement wont be visible in console.
Or in place of print dump the logs in some file.